# Change in php.ini not reflecting PHP Memory_Limit Master Value

Tags: php, apache, composer-php

I am trying to install a composer package for AWS S3 integration and came across the Composer Out of Memory issue.

Upon checking phpinfo() I could see the loaded php configuration file is /etc/php.ini and the Max Memory Limit allocated was 256M

But while checking the file memory_limit allocated was 128M. I tried to change it and then restarted the server. But whatever I do the Master value remains at 256M.

I am able to change the values locally using .htaccess but unfortunately it wont work with composer.

[Loaded Configuration File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgnvD.png)

[php.ini values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo2Ll.png)

Comment: restart server ?

Comment: Yes. Multiple times. No change

Comment: Are you able to overwrite changes using apache? 
Please check AllowOverride all in php.ini file and mod rewrite apache2 is installed? Otherwise .htacess changes not reflect

Comment: htaccess changes are reflecting. But composer running directly from /usr/local/bin for which Master php.ini to be came into effect.